# Replace encoded characters for iframes only Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

The WYSIWYYG editor in the CMS I am using is striping out the iframe code so that this code

```
<p><iframe src="http://www.example.com" frameborder="0" width="300" height="300" scrolling="no"></iframe></p>
```

appears like this when loaded on the page

```
<p>&lt;iframe src="http://www.example.com" frameborder="0" width="300" height="300" scrolling="no"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;</p>
```

I fixed it up by using this code.

```
$('p').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tt = $this.text();
    $this.html(tt.replace('&lt', '<').replace('&gt', '>'));
});
```

However if I also have other tags on the page like

```
<p><strong>Strong text </strong></p>
```

This also is getting stripped out to appear like

```
<p>Strong text </p>
```

How can I get this change to only apply to iframes?

I have tried something like this but it didn't work.

```
$this.html(tt.replace('&lt;iframe', '<iframe').replace('&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;', '</iframe>'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up getting it working by using :contains eg

```
$('p:contains("iframe")').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tt = $this.text();
    $this.html(tt.replace('&lt', '<').replace('&gt', '>'));
});
```

not the best soloution but this works for what the site is after.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all, try and find where to change the settings of your RTE. This is a common issue and you should be able control which tags are allowed.

IF you really want to hack it with jQuery, you can create your pattern, for example:

```
<p class="iframeMe" data-src="http://iframe-source" data-width="500" data-height="500"> Iframe will appear here </p>

$('.iframeMe').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $iframe = $('<iframe />').attr('src', $this.data('src')).attr('width', $this.data('width')).attr('height', $this.data('height'));
    $this.append($iframe);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this selector:

```
$('iframe').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this).parent(); // get its parent
    var tt = $this.text();
    $this.html(tt.replace('&lt', '<').replace('&gt', '>'));
});
```